# Adding script in Linux to display date at start up terminal bash shell

Tags: linux, bash

I have a hw problem where I need to make the date appear at the start up screen of the terminal in bash shell. I was able to save date script using nano, but am now stumped on how to get it to show up when launching terminal. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Run the script from your `.bash_profile`.

Comment: Or `.bashrc` if you want it in every interactive shell ...

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Or simply add the time to your prompt, if that works. E.g. add `export PS1="\[\e[0;37m\]\D{%R}\[\e[1;34m\] \h:\w> \[\e[0m\]"` to your `.bashrc`. Example has lt-gray time and blue host/directory, e.g. `15:35 wizard:~/dev/src-c/tmp/debug>` (you can just paste the prompt into your command line and hit return to test.)

Comment: Or `PS1="$(tput setaf 7)\D{%R}$(tput setaf 4) \h:\w> $(tput setaf 9)"`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a desktop shortcut launcher that will start your script in a terminal.

```
     $ gedit ~/Desktop/dateterminal.desktop
```

Copy the following (change the exec line to your script)

```
    [Desktop Entry]
    Version=1.0
    Type=Application
    Terminal=true
    Exec=/path/to/your/date/script
    Name=whatever you want
    Icon=
```

After creating right click on the launcher > Properties > Permissions > & check the Execute: box

Comment: Isn't that specific to particular distributions of Linux and not universal?

Answer (score 1):

## Here you go:

I am not really sure if you want a motd in CLI or if you want a message for everytime you opening a new tab or logging in or if it's before you logging in(MOTD) but since you have a script I guess it's in a terminal window everytime you opening a new tab:

```
mkdir -p ~/.scripts
# Put your script in ~/.scripts
echo ". ~/scripts/yourscript.sh" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! This worked perfectly! Out of curiosity if I wanted to take the date away after adding it, how would I go about doing that?